# How to abort 500 in production?

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel-5, abort, sweetalert

I have a feedback form and want to test .fail message (use sweetalert swal method). How artificially to trigger a 500 error when sending  form in production environment (in local it`s work)? Thanks for any help)

Comment: I'm assuming you have some sort of validation that prevents you from submitting an invalid POST request. Either remove the validation in your local copy of the app that can hit the production server, or use something like Postman and construct an invalid POST request yourself.

Comment: Yes, but if i a have a server error?

Comment: You don't have to submit the form to your production server if you're just trying to test how the client responds to a 500. Just run some local dummy server that will always return 500, point your form URL to it, and test it that way. There's also ways of testing failure conditions in JS without involving a server, but I've never used sweetalert so I can't give you any advice on that front unless you post some code.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation) ... I test it in local environment (all works fine), but was just interesting can I make it to production)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `500` error signals a fatal error during execution. To trigger that explicitly, simply make your app fail so it returns a non-0 status code. Throwing an exception will do, but the most straight-forward way is to simply exit with a non-0 status code:

```
exit 1;
```

You could also configure your web server to return the HTTP status code directly for specific URLs/requests; for example an .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule /my/submit/uri - [R=500]
```